# what is the difference b/w svn info and svnversion

Tags: svn

I need to tag my project with the latest revision(working copy).I thought about using svn info command,but I am doing selective updates so what i have is a working copy with mixed revision and while doing svn info it is showing some old revision.Please help to tag my source which is of  mixed revision.

I also found svnversion, will it help??
which is better for the job svn info or svnversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[svnversion](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) exposes the same information (Revision number) of [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html), but summarized.

I always used svn info to get this information.

Comment: It actually doesn't expose the same information.  Or, maybe more correctly said, svnversion may not be giving you what you want.

**svnversion** gives the revision of the repository that you've updated to, plus some other stuff.  That isn't the same thing as the last modification revision.

**svn info** gives the latest revision that you've updated to, AND the last changed revision.   

Try this by doing a checkout of a tag from a long time ago.   You'll see the revision given by svninfo is the last in your repository.

Comment: Actually `svnversion -c` will give him what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

While svnversion can be handy as per @Ivan Zhakov's answer, it does not work 100% of the time, specially with SVN version 7 working copy subfolders (I only get the result 'exported')

to be compatible in build scripts, I use svn info.

```
REVISION=$(svn info | grep -i revision | cut -f2 -d: | tr -d [:space:])
```

You can get the similar 'locally modified' flag via

```
OUTSTANDING=$(svn status | grep '^[M!DA]')
```

Answer (score 1):

To tag mixed revision WC just use copy from WC command:

```
svn copy WC URL -m "Tagged version x.x.x".
```

`svnversion` prints single version number if the working is single revision, unmodified, not switched and with URL that matches the optional TRAIL_URL arguemen If the working
copy is unusual the version number will be more complex:

```
 4123:4168     mixed revision working copy
 4168M         modified working copy
 4123S         switched working copy
 4123P         partial working copy, from a sparse checkout
 4123:4168MS   mixed revision, modified, switched working copy
```

Answer (score 1):

svnversion is most useful when you want write a build script which puts the information into a a string, for instance your build process could create a version string which is compiled into the application and which contains the output of svnversion, applied to the base directory of the working copy. Unlike 'svn info', which only gives the information of individual files or directories, svnversion will look at all the subdirectories and modify its output (see Ivan Zhakov answer) to reflect any mix of local mods or different versions. If it says just "4123" you know that you can (if all is set up right) regenerate the same build by checking out rev 4123.

Answer (score -2):

Apply `svn info` on your repo url, rather than your working copy. That is bound to be the latest:

```
svn info http://server/svn/repo
```

svnversion is not an svn command, it is a third party script. And it should be using `svn info` to iterate your working copy and  get the revisions.

Comment: (a) it's not a script, it's a binary (b) it's not 3rd party, it's part of the subversion package.